# How can I paste the value from one sheet to another using macro/vba?

Tags: excel, vba

In sheet 1, I have various items that I need to populate with a given ID in sheet 2. Example below:

**Sheet 1:**

```
Column1  Column2
----------------                   
shoe     no data   
bag      no data  
jacket   no data
```

**Sheet 2:**

```
Column1 
-------   
KL-123   
BC-223   
AK-477   
AB-987
```

If possible I would like to seek for an expert's advise or if I can get a macro to fill "sheet1 column2" with the the values in "sheet2 Colum1" just like below. Sheet1 multiplies depending upon the number of items in "sheet2".

**Sheet1**

```
Column1    Column2
------------------
shoe       KL-123           
bag        KL-123            
jacket     KL-123            
shoe       BC-223           
bag        BC-223           
jacket     BC-223          
shoe       AK-477           
bag        AK-477          
jacket     AK-477            
shoe       AB-987          
bag        AB-987         
jacket     AB-987
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Option Explicit
'Option Base 1 not really needed, my assumptions are correct
```

---

```
Sub Test()

Dim sh1 As Worksheet, sh2 As Worksheet
Dim myIDs
Dim itmRng As Range
Dim i As Long

Set sh1 =Thisworkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Set sh2 = Thisworkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")

With sh2
    '~~> get your items
    '~~> basically, below passes range values to an array
    myIDs = Application.Transpose(.Range("A1", _
            .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Address))
End With

With sh1
    '~~> get your item range
    Set itmRng = .Range("A1", .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Address)
    '~~> populate the columns
    For i = Lbound(myIDs) To Ubound(myIDs)
        '~~> iterating the array values also determines how many
        '~~> times you need to copy your item range
        itmRng.Copy itmRng.Offset((i-1)*itmRng.Rows.Count,0)
        itmRng.Offset((i-1)*itmRng.Rows.Count,1) = myIDs(i)
    Next
End With

End Sub
```

**Edit1:**
Already tested. Hope this helps you a bit.

Comment: WOW! this works really great. Thank you very much. Do you offer such training? I would love to gain more knowledge like that. Thank you

Comment: Can I ask for some adjustments on this? How can I set it to capture all items in sheet1 like if I add more columns and rows? Thank you very much. Hope you can help me with it.

Comment: Item range to select all active cells or cell with values starting A2.Thank you very much.
With sh1
    '~~> get your item range

Comment: `Do you offer such training?` I train myself. I read books, visits and helps forums like this. I play around the VBE often and practice, practice, practice. :) `How can I set it to capture all items in sheet1 like if I add more columns and rows?` Can you show example? `Item range to select all active cells or cell with values starting A2` starting A2 meaning you have headers? Btw, that code only selects a range until the last cell in A with value. So if there are empty spaces in between, it will copy it as well.

Comment: yes, I have header and I also do some modification from your first code :) because it capture from A1 but now its okay, example: if I have 50 columns in sheet1 and even if there are empty cells I would also want to copy and paste those just like what it does to bag,shoe,jacket.

Comment: column1 bag, shoe, jacket, column2 "value from sheet2" column3 black, white, yellow, column4 pcs, pair, pc. so on

Comment: item range are from Column A to D or more. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't very clear, but from what I can see it looks like
you just need to use a function, VBA (probably) is not necessary here. `=VLOOKUP(lookup_value,table_array,col_index_num,range_lookup)`

The layout of the sheet you gave in your question seems strange, and potentially backwards, but here is how the `Vlookup` would be written, given your data.

Your lookup_value will be:

```
Sheet 1:

Column1

shoe

bag

jacket
```

Your table array will be columns 1 and 2 from sheet 2. The column index number would be 2, if the first column in your table range is sheet 2 column 1.

You will want to set the `range_lookup` value to `FALSE`, since you are not looking for a range.

You would place this `Vlookup` function in Sheet 1, column 2, the column which you said is blank.

You can also get more info and some great examples of Vlookups [from the source.](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/vlookup-HP005209335.aspx)

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your reply but i doubt that vlookup will solve this issue or maybe I am just missing something here. sorry for an unclear question btw. what I would want is to populate sheet1 with data in sheet2 by copying each values from sheet2. like if I have 4 values in sheet2 then each items in sheet1 will have a corresponding   values from sheet2. shoe will have KL-123, BC-223, AK-477, AB-987 in each rows and same goes with the other items. please let me know if this make sense. Thank you

Comment: Can you post a picture of the problem?

Comment: If you want to create a macro you can just go to the developer tab, hit record macro and then record yourself manually copying and posting each value appropriately. You can then save the macro and reply it to do the exact same sequence of actions in the future. That is all a macro is, recorded actions.

If you want to use VBA you would probably want to read all the Values from sheet 2 into 3 sperate arrays, using a for loop. Perhaps one array for each type of item.

Comment: So your array for shoes would collect all the possible unique keys associated with shoes, if the value in Column whatever contained the String value `shoe`.

You could tell you're arrays to do this by use of conditional statements. Give it a shot on your own and post back, good luck.

Comment: Appreciate your reply, I only know some basics in macro. But I am unable to generate with the correct result as below:
Sheet1 
ColumnA 
Item1 
Item2 
Item3 
 
Sheet2 
ColumnA 
ID1 
ID2 
ID3 
ID4 
 
Result in Sheet1 
ColumnA ColumnB
Item1 ID1
Item2 ID1
Item3 ID1
Item1 ID2
Item2 ID2
Item3 ID2
Item1 ID3
Item2 ID3
Item3 ID3
Item1 ID4
Item2 ID4
Item3 ID4

I have 4 ID's and what I want is to multiply all contents in Sheet1 depending on how many ID's I have. CAn you help me with it? Does it make sense now? Thank you very much

Comment: It is incredibly difficult to interpret a paragraph of text into an Excel sheet without some sort of visual aid in this case.. I am unable to re-create this issue without proper screen shots.

Comment: sorry, I am not allowed to post any photo this time. need atleast 10 reputations. btw: the macro above just need to have little modification but don't know how I am supposed to do that. I just wanted to set the range not just in Col A1 but those columns and rows with values. Thank you